# Where does the か in なかった come from?

Tags: verbs, auxiliaries

So I'm trying to understand Genki's preferred past negative form of です, that is: じゃなかったです.  I'm confused by the なかった.

As I understand it from [this source](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/11/jodoushi.html), this is a combination of two 助動詞: the 連用形 form of ない continued with た.  However, [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#Japanese) lists the 連用形 form of ない as なく.

なくた sounds a lot like なかった, so it seems reasonable to assume this is a vowel shift to avoid the awkward transition between U to T in KUTA, but, since I'm a beginner, I wanted to make sure - are there other grammatical processes in place that I've missed?

Which leads me to the following overall theory:

There are five "lexemes" in play here

- じゃ -> DEWA relating the verb phrase to the rest of the sentence
- なか -> NAI informing of negation
- った -> TE informing of past
- です -> DE relating the 助動詞 to ARIMASU -> informing of "existence"

these are combined with somewhat irregular conjugation process which involves shifting verb roots and auxillary verbs into one of a few base forms and then combining them.  I assume the grammar of this process is more descriptive than prescriptive, and the speaker typically memorizes a list of common conjugations and common exceptions, rarely applying the rules to create new verb constructs.  Or is there a formal grammar to this process described somewhere?

Comment: Hi, I was sure I had seen a question about this before and here it is, hopefully this one helps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73025/origin-of-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f

Comment: Yep, just as @OtheJared has posted -- that linked thread should answer your questions about ～かった, the past-tense ending for all ～い adjectives.